# Angular directive: Error: Failed to load template: foo.html (script tag with id="foo.html")

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have done this a bunch of times but am running a test script and now am getting a 404 error when trying to load the template.

I have added the template to the main html file in a script tag as normal:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<script type="text/ng-template" id=“foo.html”>
    <span>{{cmInsertHtml.name}}</span>
</script>


<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in abc" cm-insert-html="obj"></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

The directive calls the templateUrl

```
app.directive('cmInsertHtml', function () {

    return {
    scope: {
        cmInsertHtml: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "foo.html"
}
}]);
```

...and just for completeness, here's the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.abc = {0: {name: "A"}, 1: {name: "B"}, 2: {name: "C"}, 3: {name: "D"}};
});
```

So I have the template safely ensconced in the html code, but Angular looks for the file foo.html, which doesn't actually exists. I know I must bee missing something obvious, but can't see the wood for trees!

Here's the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9OobsjXplp5anLfsr3QB?p=preview).

Please help!

Comment: What am I missing - you don't have a foo.html. Add that and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/WvddvEeUlR05Npbwdbi9?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the quotes around the id of the template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id=“foo.html”>
    <span>{{cmInsertHtml.name}}</span>
</script>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html">
    <span>{{cmInsertHtml.name}}</span>
</script>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/C9D51q04djLB071fvz9p?p=preview

Comment: OMG - I told you I couldn't see the wood for the trees! That's what you get for copying and pasting code I guess! Well spotted - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You had special quotes around `foo.html` which made it fail. That sucks, but here it is [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/9l1ipO?p=preview) (you aren't losing your mind).